# How to connect two virtual machines with accessible private IP address

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ip, linux-kvm

I am trying to have some VMs on two Ubuntu hosts using KVM (two seperate machines).

I want all these VMs to be accessible with their private IPs (or public IPs). I know the local IPs of the VMs can not be used since they are behind NAT. Kindly let me know the simplest options and requirements for this purpose.

To be more specific:

1. How they should be physically connected (a cable, a hub, a router, etc..)?  The two machines are currently connected to a WIFI router. But since WIFI routers are sometimes busy and have high latency, I am looking for a better option.
2. How should the virtual machines be configured, so their IP addresses would be visible to others?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the 2 VMS on 2 separate machines?

Comment: Yes, I have two machines and two KVM installed on them. I on each machine I have about 5 VMs So I want all VMs be accessible from each other.

Comment: Are the two Ubuntu machines in the same local network? I forgot to address that.

Comment: Thanks, you have answered part of my question. The other part is how to connect these two machines physically (if possible with low latency) . (I mean a cable, a router a hub ,,...)

Comment: I'm asking again, are the two Ubuntu hosts in the same local network under the same router? What is the topology in your network? I need that information so I can answer your 1st question.

Comment: They are connected to the same WIFI router but I guess it is not good because it has high latency

Comment: Add that information into your question. I will edit my answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should they be physically connected?

If the distance is not too great and you don't have many machines in your local network (e.g. it's only those 2 Ubuntu hosts), then your option would be to **directly connect the 2 Ubuntu hosts to the router via an UTP cable** (Ubuntu host 1 is connected to the Router via a cable, Ubuntu host 2 is connected to the Router via a cable as well). By using direct cable connection you'll avoid the higher latencies that WiFi has.

However, if the distance is too great and you have more machines that need a direct connection, then you can use a **[switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch)**. The **switch** has to be connected via one of its ports to the router, and then you connect your machines to the other ports of the switch.

> How should the IP addresses of the virtual machines be visible to other VMs/hosts?

Configure **Public bridge** networking for your virtual machines. This will assign them IP addresses in your local network, so you can access them via your host or other virtual machines that are configured in the same way.

See [How to configure Public Bridge @ KVM Networking](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking) for a detailed guide on how to achieve that.

You can also check [this article from VMware](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html) which explains what bridging is.

**Note:** If you want only the VMs to be able to access each other, and not access them from other hosts, you can use **Private bridge** configuration, which will setup a local network **only** for the virtual machines, so they will be in a seperate network.

Comment: Thanks, you have answered part of my question. The other part is how to connect these two machines physically (if possible with low latency) . (I mean a cable, a router a hub ,,...)

Comment: @amirmohamadhatami Please edit that into your question as well. And what do you mean physically connect them? Are the two Ubuntu machines under the same router?

Comment: I have already edited them. I mean the physical layer. They are connected to the same WIFI router but I guess it is not good because it has high latency

Comment: Simply using a cable connected to the router is more than enough to bypass the high latency.

Comment: Thanks and would that also work if I use a private bridge config? (Or I should set some settings in the router).  To be more specific I am afraid that these public IPs change over the time and If they change I would have to reinstall my programs on the VMs which is time consuming.

Comment: Yes, the physical layer doesn't care about how you've configured your private network. It's just to avoid higher latency. And if you're afraid of the IP addresses changing, you can configure static IP addresses - [Set a static IP address on Ubuntu](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu), but it shouldn't be a problem, unless those applications need to know the **exact** IP of the other VM.

Comment: They need to need to know the exact IP of other VMs.

Comment: @amirmohamadhatami No problem, if my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as a correct answer. And if they need to know the exact IP, then configure static IP addresses - refer to the article I linked.

Comment: I need to have more bridges (about six bridges) but every bridge should be connected to one eth port as I can see. While I only have one eth port in my PC. Is there any solution do you think?