# Creating multiple bridges connected to one eth port

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, bridge, linux-kvm

I want to create  6 VMs in KVM on an ubuntu 16.04. But I want these VMs be accessible from outside directly. To explain more, I have another PC that is connected to first one and I want to be able to ping all VMs with specified IPs.

So I need to bridge them according to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1341120/how-to-connect-two-virtual-machines-with-accessible-private-ip-address). The problem is that I only have one ethernet port and as far as I know I can use it just for one of the VMs.

Is there a way to create 6 bridges for the VMs?

Thanks

Comment: You misunderstand how it works. You (or more typically the software) creates a bridge interface, then each VM is added to the bridge.

Comment: I want all the VMs have their separate IPs accessible form outside (another PC connected). If I use only one bridge it acts like a NAT so there is no different b/w them from outside. The KVM itself creates a bridge, but all VMs are connected to it.

Comment: Not so. NAT and bridging are unrelated. You can set up a bridge which is not natted, and which gives machines their own IP. (I've done this)

Comment: Do you own a vlan capable switch?

Comment: I have a router

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding networking terminology a bit here.  A bridge on Linux has nothing to do with NAT or routing..  It's literally just an Ethernet switch implemented entirely in software.

In your case, you should be able to achieve what you appear to want with exactly one bridge with all the VM's connected to that bridge.  From there, you have two options:

1. Use the host system as an actual bridge for the VM's by connecting one of your regular Ethernet interfaces to the bridge.  This will do no routing and no NAT.  Each VM will get it's IP and network info from whatever DHCP server is running on your main network, and will be individually accessible with whatever IP address it gets assigned.  This is the approach that I would recommend using unless you *really* need the host system to act as a firewall, your primary network is not Ethernet, or you can't set the bridge up during system startup before NetworkManager starts trying to get addresses.  The advantage here is simplicity.
2. Use the host system as a router.  This requires not connecting the bridge to any physical interfaces, and some manual setup of iptables or nftables rules to get the routing right.  This approach has three advantages over the first one, you can use the host as a firewall, your main network link doesn't have to be Ethernet, and it can be easily setup after you already have a network address for the host system.  You can do NAT this way, but it's not mandatory (though it is far easier to set up than other routing schemes).  You can also do any of various other address mappings, including a 1:1 mapping which sounds like what you want.

In either case, you need to be setting this up *outside* of NetworkManager (in fact, if you're running these on a server, just get rid of NetworkManager, it's a waste of processor cycles unless you regularly need to switch network configurations), because it will try to force the second setup on you and otherwise get in your way.

Comment: Thanks, I have created the bridge, the VM has internet access but the main host does not have. I have also a wireless connection in addition to the ethernet port which is used to connect to the bridge. But I dont have internet access. Is there a way to have internet access?

Comment: @amirmohamadhatami You can configure an IP address (or run a DHCP client) on the bridge just like you can on any other network interface.